# I have a button in my item template and I want to program it so that it directs me to that specific job details

Tags: c#, sql, .net, visual-studio

I have a page where I list all jobs. I have to program a button so that when I click on it, it directs me to that specific job details. How can I do that. I have tried navigateUrl but when I click on the button, nothing happens.

**Here is my code for my item template**

```
<asp:ListView ID="lsvJob" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="nf-item branding coffee spacing">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-30">
                    <div class="service_box">
                        <figure>
                            <asp:Image ID="imgposter" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("HO_Image", "~/Images/{0}") %>'
                                runat="server" Height="300px" Width="300px" ImageAlign="Top" />
                        </figure>
                        <h3><%#Eval("Job_Name") %></h3>
                        <p>
                            <b>Employer Name:</b> <%# Eval("HO_LastName") %> <%# Eval("HO_FirstName") %>
                            <br />
                            <b>Email Address:</b> <%# Eval("HO_Email") %>
                        </p>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkmovdetails" runat="server" Text="View Details"
                            NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Job_ID","~/jobdetails.aspx?id={0}")%>' CommandName="btnAccess" CssClass="btn btn-info"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

**code behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace moCoolMaid
{
    public partial class listjob : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private string _conString =
WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MaidCS"].ConnectionString;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create Connection
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_conString))
            {
                // Create Command
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = " SELECT tblHO.*, tblJob.* FROM tblHO, tblJob WHERE tblJob.HO_ID=tblHO.HO_ID";
                //Create DataReader
                SqlDataReader reader;
                con.Open();
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                //Bind the reader to the repeater control
                lsvJob.DataSource = reader;
                lsvJob.DataBind();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Code in my jobdetail web form**

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dsvJob" runat="server"  AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="10" GridLines="Vertical">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="Gainsboro" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Job_Name" HeaderText="Job_Name" SortExpression="Job_Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Job_Desc" HeaderText="Job_Desc" SortExpression="Job_Desc" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Job_Salary" HeaderText="Job_Salary" SortExpression="Job_Salary" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Deadline_Date" HeaderText="Deadline_Date" SortExpression="Deadline_Date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Min_Experience" HeaderText="Min_Experience" SortExpression="Min_Experience" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Min_Qualification" HeaderText="Min_Qualification" SortExpression="Min_Qualification" />
        </Fields>

        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000084" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black"  />

    </asp:DetailsView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MaidCS %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Job_Name], [Job_Desc], [Job_Salary], [Deadline_Date], [Type], [Min_Experience], [Min_Qualification] FROM [tblJob]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove navigateUrl property from LinkButton and below one.

```
PostBackUrl="imagepage.aspx?v=<%#Eval("id") %>"
```

from query string you will get jobID. read JobId and display record.

Thanks, hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Command Name does not work like this. Use below code for redirection

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkmovdetails" runat="server" Text="View Details" PostBackUrl='~/jobdetails.aspx?id=<%#Eval("Job_ID") %>' CssClass="btn btn-info" />
```